# servlet could not create cookie file in IE11

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, servlets, cookies

In the servlet class of java,I use

```
Cookie c2 = new Cookie("email","jacky@123.com");
c2.setMaxAge(3000);
response.addCookie(c2);
```

Then I use IE11 to access the servlet,without closing the browser,the second time to access the servlet,I can also use `request.getCookies()` in the servlet to get cookie infomation 
But I can't find the relevant cookie file in the `Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files` which I can find other website's cookie file,so I think the cookie may store just in the memory
So I try to change firefox to access the servlet,and finally I find the cookie infomation in the file `cookies.sqlite` in the firefox's relevant folder in the disk
So how can I do to make IE11 create cookie file?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi, use the File>Properties menu of IE to determine which IE security zone your site/dev environment is mapping it to... there are IE security restrictions for scripting of Java applets. Assuming your targeting an internal (intranet) web site, then it should map to the Intranet zone. There is a separate store for cookies on low integrity processes.. shell:cookies\low

Comment: @Rob Parsons Thanks,I found the folder and there are some cookies files in it,but I can't find the cookies relate to the code in the question. So I think the browser just doesn't create the cookies from the code,and for proving it, I close the browser and use request.getCookies() in the servlet to get cookies information,and I can't get the cookies.Do you know what I can set to make the browser to create the cookies,thanks.